# Diference between IPTABLES RAW PREROUTING and MANGLE PREROUTING

Tags: networking, security, iptables, firewall

I'm looking for configs to prevent DDoS attacks and UPnP Flood, since I've started to create rules, every advice was to add rules to filter table, but it takes too much CPU process, so started to create rules in `MANGLE` table, but last weeks raw table helped me a lot, but I didn't found too much difference between `MANGLE`, `PREROUTING` and raw `PREROUTING`, theologically.

My question is simple:
the difference of those and why not write rules in `PREROUTING` and leave `INPUT` table as it is?

Comment: You will need to provide more information on what you are trying to achieve. Are you setting up a router or a server? Also, this question has answers in various other (non-Ubuntu-specific) sites. For instance [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/iptables) is an excellent exposition that answers your questions.

Comment: thats not what i was seeking, but i've found some hints, rules added to raw table still is not translated from nat, so its not identified some kind of packets, adding rules to INPUT TABLE may be more effective, but it load more CPU, there are some rules to raw table and mangle table that could lower some malicious incoming packs.